# Backbone routing error on page load with forward slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have some routes set up in a Backbone app with forward slashes:

```
 app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        'dashboard/:locationId/:product/:year': 'dashboard',
        'bargraph': 'bargraph'
    },
 ....
```

On document ready, I start the Backbone history plugin and after that, my routes work correctly and the functions are run as I would expect.

```
 $(function () {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

However, if I reload the page with the routes already in the URL, I get an error (in Chrome but probably other browsers too):

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dashboard/3/productA/2009
```

I only get this error for the routes with the forward slashes in there. My bargraph route seems to work fine on page load without the forward slashes.

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the timing of the call to the `Backbone.history.start` function. The easiest solution is to get rid of the forward slashes in the URL and use some other URL safe delimiter. But it even breaks on page load with URL encoded versions of the `/`. And it looks less good.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dashboard%2F3%2FInVigor 8440%2F2009
```

Unfortunately the error is coming from a minified version of jQuery so I don't know if this is a common issue or something specific happening in some obscure location on the site.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the likely culprit? Possible workarounds?

**Edit: Adding Stacktrace**

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dashboard/3/productA/2009 VM142

```
    standard.js:2$.error VM142 
    standard.js:2bc VM142 standard.js:2
    bk VM142     standard.js:2
q.querySelectorAll.bk VM142 standard.js:2
$ VM142 standard.js:2p.fn.extend.find VM142 standard.js:2
p.fn.p.init VM142 standard.js:2p VM142 standard.js:2c VM149 BCSUS_scopeScripts_B020D85856E4B758EB7D71EC4F5B7E5F.js:1
(anonymous function) VM149 BCSUS_scopeScripts_B020D85856E4B758EB7D71EC4F5B7E5F.js:1
p.Callbacks.k VM142 standard.js:2
p.Callbacks.l.fireWith VM142 standard.js:2
p.extend.ready VM142 standard.js:2D
```

It's minified but standard.js contains a copy of jQuery and other plugins. Line nubmers aren't very helpful but maybe the function names are helpful in some way.

Comment: what does the call trace look like for this error in the console?

Comment: Doesn't the `q.querySelectorAll` in the stack trace suggest that jQuery is raising the error when trying to parse a selector? Any chance that you can reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net? This doesn't smell like a Backbone router problem to me.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short. It was an errant jQuery selector grabbing the hash on page load. Not a Backbone routing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the issue and it wasn't anything to do with Backbone routing. There was a section of the site that was feeding the `location.hash` into a selector on page load. **face-palm**

```
if (location.hash) {
     ...
       doSomething(location.hash); // <-- feeds into a jQuery selector
    }

function doSomething(id) {
    var container = $(id);
 .....
```

This was running before the js app starts up and caused the issue. Easy solution in the end was to wrap this in a `try catch` clause.

Thanks Mu and Quince for pointing this out.